# Text não aparece usando React Hooks com Redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-hooks

Estou tentando pegar uma string salva no meu state do store e colocar ela em um componente de texto, mas o texto não esta aparecendo.

Pra chamar a string, estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'

const OhSnap = () => {


    const text = useSelector(state => state.data)

    return(
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 15,color:'white',fontWeight:'bold',textAlignVertical: 'center',margin: 5,textAlign:'center'}}>{text}</Text>
      <View>
)}

export default OhSnap
```

No meu reducer eu declarei variavel da seguinte forma:

```
const initialState = {
  data: 'Please show up on the component'
};
```

Não entendo porque isso estaria errado..

PS:So tenho um tela que usa Hooks, e uso o redux antigo com mapstatetoprops em outras diversas telas.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade, acredito que esteja montando errado.
Vou tentar fazer um passo a passo para ti. O erro não está no useSelector. Está usando ele de maneira correta. O problema é que o que o useSelector está tentando selecionar não é um state do store. A configuração está errada. Existe toda uma estrutura por trás, veja, espero que consiga fazer, caso já saiba e o erro não é isto peço desculpas.

Primeiramente, você deve fazer seu componente principal ser envolvido pelo componente de contexto do react-redux, geralmente o componente principal é o index.js.

*index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './app';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

*app.js*

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import Store from "./store";
import OutroComponente from './components/outro';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={Store}>
      <OutroComponente />
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

O provider precisa da configuração da store que está no arquivo store.js solicitado acima. Veja o codigo do arquivo store.js

*store.js*

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import dataReducer from './dataReducer';

const Store = createStore(combineReducers({
    data: dataReducer,
    // Outros state caso precise aqui
  }
);

export default Store;
```

Criei apenas um state na store chamado data já que é o que você espera, mas ai você pode adicionar quantos state quiser. É este nome que vc vincula por meio do *useSelector* no componente.

Agora vc precisa de configurar o reducer do data, deixei em outro arquivo também por questão de organização. Ficaria assim:

*dataReducer.js*

```
import { LOAD_SCHEDULED_SERVICES } from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = 'Please show up on the component'

const dataReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_DATA:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default dataReducer;
```

O SET_DATA é usado com o hooks **useDispatch** para mudar o valor da store e o **useSelector** para buscar o valor da store.

Logo, em qualquer componente que esteja agora, caso queira pegar o valor do state data da store basta:

```
const text = useSelector(state => state.data)
```

Espero ter te ajudado, qualquer coisa, se confundi o que queria dizer peço desculpas. Valeu mano

Comment: Opa, desculpas a demora, mas consegui resolver o problema, e era um passo intermediario, para acessar o componente onde uso o selector ele passa por um outro componente e esse componente não estava conectado com redux, foi so conectar ele que deu tudo certo :D